# Can I put another ContentPage in ContentPage inside TabbedPage?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, content-pages

I have TabbedPage. This has multiple ContentPages inside.

E.g; I have a settings page, I want a new page to be opened by clicking a button in the settings page, hiding the tab part.

When I do as below, the new page is gone, but I have to re-create the TabbedPage to return. Is it possible to create a new page in view with tabbedPage hidden in the background? Can you help if possible?

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new PageTrial());
```

I'm new to Xamarin sorry if it's a simple rendering.

Comment: use a Modal page.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/modal

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't even know it existed. Now I'll try to do it in a MVVM-friendly way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original Poster (OP) said Jason's suggestion of [Modal page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/modal) solves their need.